# Proof of the validity of a proposition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We are trying  to decide  whether the proposition: $(\exists A \subset E)(\forall B \subset E)(A \cup B =E)$ is true or not. I believe it's because for $A=E$ this proposition is always true. But I came across the following proof: since $A$ can be any set included in $E$ it can be the complement of $B$ (in $E$) and in that case this proposition is always true. But I'm not convinced because I think that $B$ can't be only one set ($\forall B$ included in $E$) and $A$ can't be the complement of every set included in $E$ . But I'm not so sure . So if I'm wrong please explain why. And  if I'm right help me find a prof to convince a colleague of mine (who is convinced - unlike myself - by this proof). Thanks in advance

Comment: The second proof, if it were valid, could also be used to show $(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}) (\forall m \in \mathbb{N}) (m < n)$ which is certainly a false statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by $\subset$ you mean "is a subset of" (which I usually denote $\subseteq$), rather than "is a proper subset of" (which would disqualify the choice $A=E$):

You are right to say $A=E$ works. You are also right to dismiss the complement argument, because all that shows is the very different result that $\forall B\subseteq E\exists A\subseteq E(A\cup B=E)$. In general $\exists A\forall B\varphi (A,\,B)$ shouldn't be confused with $\forall B\exists A\varphi (A,\,B)$.